# Is it secure to use apex:remoteObjects to update objects via JS?

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, remote-objects

I have some concerns about security when using remoteObjects

```
<apex:remoteObject>
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Lead" fields="Id,FirstName"/>
</apex:remoteObjects>

lead.retrieve({
            where: {
                Id: {
                    eq: leadId.Id
                }
            }
        }, function (err, records) {
            if (err) {
                alert(err);
            } else {
                ...

            }
        });
```

Later on I updated that lead:

```
lead.update([leadId.Id], {
                FirstName: leadFirstName
            }, function (error, records) {
});
```

That JS is exposed on external sights eg. web to lead

Do you think do it outside the custom controller is more secure than in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Best Practices for Using Remote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_considerations.htm) (emphasis mine):

> Consider the following points when you’re deciding where to put your organization’s business logic.
>
> - Security and consistency: Remember that users can lose their network connection in mid-transaction, or *alter the way that your page’s JavaScript executes with Firebug and other tools*. Remote Objects enforces your validation rules, triggers, sharing rules, field level security, and other data access restrictions, but *if you put business rules in JavaScript instead of Salesforce, those can be interrupted, altered, or bypassed*.
> - Testability: Business logic on the server side can use the many tools that Salesforce provides for testing. For this reason, we encourage you to put complex behavior in Apex and use the Apex test framework to verify that it works as you intend.
> - Performance: If your processing needs to look at many records as part of a transaction, but won’t display them in the browser, we recommend you avoid sending that data to the client, and instead process the data “locally” on the server. Think about what data your page needs to do its work, and make sure you’re not needlessly copying it over the wire.